# Recursive insertion sorting not working in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

```
    import sys
```

## Firstly created a function and passed arr and n as arguments.

```
    def recursiveinsertionsort(arr,n):
```

## Base case:when n=0 or n=1.

```
        if n<=1:
        return
```

## now call the sequence till the remaining n-1 terms.

```
    recursiveinsertionsort(arr,n-1)
    temp=arr[n-1]
    j=n-2
    while j>=0 and arr[j+1] < arr[j]:
        arr[j+1]=arr[j]
        j-=1
    arr[j+1]=temp


    def printArray(arr,n):
        for i in range(n):
            print(arr[i])


    arr=[15,12,26,98,45,3]
    n=len(arr)
    recursiveinsertionsort(arr,n)
    printArray(arr,n)
```

## The output is not sorted.

Comment: The essence of an insertion sort is to (a) find where the value-to-be-inserted belongs in the stuff-already-sorted, then to (b) insert it.  So you need to scan `arr[]` for the first value `> temp`, and then insert at that point -- moving stuff up `arr[]`, which will overwrite the location you read `temp` from.

Comment: @ChrisHall  Please  post the syntax of what you are trying to say.Would be of great help.Thanks in advance

Comment: After the call `recursiveinsertionsort(arr,n-1)` (1) you have `n >= 2`; (2) you know that `arr[0]` through to (and including) `arr[n-2]` are in order, and (3) the next item to sort into place is `temp = arr[n-1]` -- so far so good.  So now (a) scan from `arr[0]` up to `arr[n-2]` to find `arr[j]`, the first value > `temp`.  Then (b) `temp` belongs at `arr[j]`, but everything from `arr[j]` to `arr[n-2]` (inclusive) needs to be moved up to `arr[j+1]` to `arr[n-1]` (which overwrites `arr[n-1]`, where `temp` was read from).  That said, you do need to look out for the case of `temp > `arr[n-2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop condition, change `arr[j+1] < arr[j]` to `arr[j] > temp`.

As mentioned in the comments, the insertion sort algorithm works by finding the position where `temp` should be moved to in the array. Check out [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-insertion-sort/) for more about recursive insertion sort.

Comment: Thanks for the link.It is of great help.The change you proposed is useful but  arr[j+1] < arr[j] where j = n-2 means arr[n-1] < arr[n-2] from virtual implementation point of view and arr[j] > temp means the same as in my syntax that is arr[n-2] >arr[n-1].

Comment: When I ran your code with the change I proposed, the sorting works as expected! Are you still getting an error?

Comment: Yes the sorting is working fine after the change but I am curious about the flow of control and conditional statement you proposed and the one used in my code are the same still it works with changed one and gives incorrect output with the original one.Can you explain why it is not working with my code although the conditions are the same?@emarteca

Comment: The conditions are not equivalent. In your version you are basically looking for the first place where the array is out of order -- this is not the insertion sort algorithm. With my code, it finds the index where the current element (`temp`) belongs in the array.
If you work through an example of sorting with both approaches, you'll see the difference.